# LayerList layer click event

Tags: dojo, arcgis-js-api

I want to handle an event once the user clicks on a layer in layer list. and based on some conditions i want to toggle the layer visibility. 
some this like;

```
     on(layerNode,"click",function(event){
        // some condition to toggle the layer visibility
      });
```

I couldn't find any help in Esri js api help.
How I can handle this.

Comment: your using `esri/dijit/LayerList` , some additional code , information would be helpfull

Comment: I forgot to mention I work with JS Api 4.5. it dosent have esri/dijit/LayerList

Comment: I am not sure but if you don't have to click on layer, you can use custom action with trigger-action https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html#events-summary